# Proving that a relation is antisymmetric

Tags: proof-writing, relations

I'm stucked with proving the following proposition.

We have given a set $X$, a non-empty set $I$ and a family $(r_i)_{i \in I}$ of relations on $X$. For $x,y \in X$ we have $x \ r \ y$, if for all $i \in I$ we always have $x \ r_i \ y$. Provide a proof for: If there exists $i \in I$ such that $r_i$ is antisymmetric, then $r$ is antisymmetric.

My intuition says that the proposition is false, because it assumes "there exists $i \in I$ such that $r_i$ is antisymmetric ..." and not "for all $i \in I$, $r_i$ is antisymmetric". Is this correct? What would the proof look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $xry$ and $yrx$ then $xr_my$ and $yr_mx$ for all $m$. In particular $xr_i y$ and $yr_i x$ so $x=y. $

Comment: I don‘t really understand your proof. Why did you write „for all m“? The proposition says „if there exists...“.

Comment: 1. If you want to prove $r$ is antisymmetric you start with the assumption that $xry$ and $yrx$ and then show that $x=y$. $\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\quad\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad$ 
2. $xry$ means precisely that $xr_my$ for all $m$. Now we use the fact that there exists an $i$ such that $xr_iy$, that is, one of the $m$'s has to be this $i$. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, I think I got it :)

Comment: One more question on this. I think my problem was to understand the sentence "For $x,y \in X$ we have $x \ r \ y$, if for all $i \in I$ we always have $x \ r_i \ y$." From this you deduced "$xry$ means that $xr_my$ for all $m$". Is that right? Could please explain me shortly how I'm supposed to interpret "For $x,y \in X$ we have $x \ r \ y$, if for all $i \in I$ we always have $x \ r_i \ y$."?